# array method(s) inaccessible with MyObject.prototype.reduce callback

Tags: javascript, arrays, callback, reduce, spread

So, I'm trying out some prototyping, and have had success implementing forEach on the prototype to handle its array of objects. The arrow function callback works fine, and I thought the same thing might work for .reduce(), however, as you can see, the notation which works for a normal Array does not work for my ArraySet prototype. On a side note, the same function in arrow notation does not work.

What's missing in my understanding of what's happening here so that I can fix this and move on?

```js
function ArraySet(items) {
  // this._items = []
  this._items = items
}

ArraySet.prototype.forEach = function forEach(cb) {
   return this._items.forEach(cb);
}
  
ArraySet.prototype.reduce = function reduce(cb) {
  return this._items.reduce(cb);
}

let arr = new ArraySet([{
    key1: 'property2',
    key3: 'propertyx'
  },
  {
    key1: 'property4',
    key3: 'propertyy'
  },
  {
    key1: 'climate change',
    key3: 'propertyx'
  },
  {
    key1: 'climate change',
    key3: 'propertyx'
  },
])

arr.forEach(el => {
    console.log(el)
});

x = arr.reduce(function (map, obj) {
    if (obj.key3 === 'propertyx'){
        map.push(obj.key1)
    }
    return map
}, []) //<-- final argument is the instantiating literal of the reigning map type: [], {}, ''
```

EDIT:
Thanks to Maheer Ali's answer detailing the use of the spread operator (...) the problem was easily solved. Maheer excellently expands on other functions where the same approach will apply.

Digging into the why, I learned before the spread operactor came along .apply() was customarily used in function calls to ensure all required arguments were available in the execution. The spread operator has evolved from applicability to arrays (like a list of arguments) since it was introduced to also include objects. It can also copy an array, replacing arr.splice().

Here's an adaptation of one of the examples on the MDN:

```js
function myFunction(v, w, x, y, ...z) {
  console.log(v + ' ' + w + ' ' + x + ' ' + y + ' ' + z)
}
var args = [0, 1];
myFunction(-1, ...args, 2, ...[3, 8]);
```

More available in the reference material: [Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: This is because you don't pass the init value to the built-in reduce in `_items.reduce`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `reduce()` have two parameters one is the callback and second is initial value of accumulator. So you need to use rest parameters for the methods and then pass all parameters to `reduce()`

**Note:** In `reduce()` you usually pass second argument. In `forEach()`,`map()` there is also a second optional parameter. That parameter will be `this` binded to callback passed to particular method.If you need to use that make sure to do the same as `reduce()`

See the below working snippet

```js
function ArraySet(items) {
  // this._items = []
  this._items = items
}

ArraySet.prototype.forEach = function forEach(cb) {
   return this._items.forEach(cb);
}
  
ArraySet.prototype.reduce = function reduce(...args) {
  return this._items.reduce(...args);
}

let arr = new ArraySet([{
    key1: 'property2',
    key3: 'propertyx'
  },
  {
    key1: 'property4',
    key3: 'propertyy'
  },
  {
    key1: 'climate change',
    key3: 'propertyx'
  },
  {
    key1: 'climate change',
    key3: 'propertyx'
  },
])

arr.forEach(el => {
    console.log(el)
});

x = arr.reduce((map, obj) => {
    if (obj.key3 === 'propertyx'){
        map.push(obj.key1)
    }
    return map
}, []) //<-- final argument is the instantiating literal of the reigning map type: [], {}, ''

console.log(x)
```

> On a side note, the same function in arrow notation does not work

The arrow function doesn't have their own `this` bindings. They use `this` of parent scope. As you are are using `this` in your methods so you can't use Arrow functions. Prototype methods can't be ever written with arrow functions.

Comment: I should clarify my observation about arrow functions; it should read '...the same function call in arrow notation does not work.'.
At the time I made the remark my thinking was running along the lines the function call was somehow involved, and not how the argument list was dealt with. In your fix, the arrow function makes the call.
The thoroughness of your answer makes me glad to have made the slip, as the information about the limitations of arrow functions not having a 'this' and the implications around their attempted use in prototype method composition really rounds the answer. Thanks.